# I gave permission to edit sudoers.co file to each user

Tags: permissions, sudo

I gave permission to edit sudoers.co file to each user and now i cant use sudo, because ubuntu don't allow to. I don't have access to root user. any ideas how to fix that?

I tried to enter recovery mode to enter root, but root user don't have any password and there is no access to it

Comment: How did you give permissions? Adding them to the sudoers file using `visudo` should work. Using `chmod` to change the file permissions to anything other than `0440` and owner `root:root` will break `sudo`. Your option now is to from a live image and fix what you did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.